# Problemas de Validação com jQuery Mask

Tags: jquery

Tenho isso no meu arquivo javascript mas não sei porque não está funcionando nos meus campos.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#number").mask('00000');
    $("#open-hour").mask('00:00');
    $("#close-hour").mask('00:00');
    $("#date-foundation").mask('00/00/0000');
    $("input[name=number]").mask("000000");
    $("#cnpj").mask('00.000.000/0000-00');



    $('#number-phone').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 15) { // Celular com 9 dígitos + 2 dígitos DDD e 4 da máscara
            $('#number-phone').mask('(00) 00000-0009');
        } else {
            $('#number-phone').mask('(00) 0000-00009');
        }
    });

    showHours();
    showMenuPhones();
});
```

Na minha página php:

```
<script src="libs/assets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs-without-icon">
<?php
/* DATE FOUNDATION */
if ($Menu->getFundationDate() == NULL) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='dateFoundation' class='input-without-icon metade-without' placeholder='Data de Fundação' id='date-foundation' />";
} else {
    $dateF = date_create($Menu->getFundationDate());
    echo "<input type='text' name='dateFoundation' class='input-without-icon metade-without' placeholder='Data de Fundação' id='date-foundation' value='" . date_format($dateF, 'dmY') . "' />";
}

/* CNPJ */
if ($Menu->getCnpj() == NULL) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='cnpj' class='input-without-icon metade-without' placeholder='CNPJ (números)' id='cnpj'/>";
} else {
    echo "<input type='text' name='cnpj'     class='input-without-icon metade-without' placeholder='CNPJ (números)' id='cnpj' value='{$Menu->getCnpj()}'/>";
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: Você importou o plugin jQuery na sua página e o script do plugin ? Verifique no console de erros do navegador se te apresenta algum erro. E se possível, poste os campos do seu HTML também.

Comment: Na minha página php aonde estão meus campos eu importei o caminho do jquery..  <script src="libs/assets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

Comment: Certo. E você viu se está dando algum erro no console ?

Comment: Não está. Nem está pegando parece.

Comment: Posta os campos do HTML pra vermos.

Comment: Postei por exemplo o do cnpj e da data.

Comment: Sua página está no ar ? Não está dando nenhum erro mesmo ? Aparentemente não tem nada errado.

Comment: Pois é, não consigo encontrar o erro.

Comment: Veja, fiz um teste simples no JSFiddle e funcionou. https://jsfiddle.net/0spxjok8/1/